# jQuery Accordion: Activating a Panel on clicking a Jumplink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not great with jQuery when it comes to manipulating javascript.  I have this large file that I condensed into this fiddle.  The format needs to be the same, and what I'm trying to do is:
When clicking on the Jumplink in Question 4, it should open the panel in Question 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/v5heud2x/1/

```js
 $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
     $( ".active" ).accordion({
 active: false,
  collapsible: true,
});
  });
```

```css
div > p {
background:green;
}
.active{
    height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
<li class="active">
    <h3><a href="www.google.com" name="google">Question 1</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Answer 1</p>
        </div>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <h3><a href="www.mangahere.com">Question 2</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Answer 2</p>
        </div>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <h3><a href="www.twitter.com">Question 3</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Answer 3</p>
        </div>
</li>
<li class="active">
    <h3><a href="www.facebook.com">Question 4</a></h3>
        <div>
            <p>Answer 4 <a href="#google">(jumplink to answer 1)</a></p>
        </div>
</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you meant. The main thing I did is to trigger the click event on the q1.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/n1k3crnm/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <li class="active">
         <h3 id="q1"><a href="www.google.com" name="google">Question 1</a></h3>

        <div>
            <p>Answer 1</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
         <h3><a href="www.mangahere.com">Question 2</a></h3>

        <div>
            <p>Answer 2</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
         <h3><a href="www.twitter.com">Question 3</a></h3>

        <div>
            <p>Answer 3</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
         <h3><a href="www.facebook.com">Question 4</a></h3>

        <div>
            <p id="q4">Answer 4 <a href="#google">(jumplink to answer 1)</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
     $("#accordion").accordion();
     $(".active").accordion({
         active: false,
         collapsible: true,
     });
 });

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#q4").click(function () {
         $( "#q1" ).trigger( "click" );
     });
 });
```

**CSS**

```
div > p {
    background:green;
}
.active {
    height:500px;
}
```

**Option 2**

you can remove the `q1` id and change the `js` to:

```
 $("#q4").click(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", 0);
 });
```

Comment: That worked perfectly but it didn't work.  This is the site I'm trying to fix.  I'm taking it from another developer and unsure of why it doesn't work:https://www.pbgc.gov/prac/prem/online-premium-filing-with-my-paa/faq-for-practitioners.html

Comment: LOL sorry, I meant that your fiddle worked perfectly but syncing it with my code for the website didn't work out.  I obviously changed the classes and ID's around to match the ones I have but didn't work.

Comment: Check the console for errors. I will help more in about 30 min

Comment: Nope, but I'll go ahead and give you Best answer, I'm going to work on it more today